# When you want to say "before", is it better to use both "déjà" and "avant" than to use either of them?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, adverbes

I often see both "déjà" and "avant" used in a single sentence to each mean "before". Doesn’t this come across as redundant? Does each of the following three sentences mean the same thing despite the different choice of words?

> On ne s'est pas déjà rencontrés quelque part avant ?

Par contre :

> On ne s'est pas déjà rencontrés quelque part?

Ou bien :

> On ne s'est pas rencontrés quelque part avant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Déjà* et *avant* dans la même phrase sont redondants, et donc à éviter.

Les deux formules expriment que la rencontre a pu être réalisée :

---

> On ne s'est pas *déjà* rencontrés quelque part ?

... on ne sait pas quand, mais il semble que c'est la seconde fois que l'on se rencontre.

*Déjà* indique que ce n'est pas nouveau.

---

> On ne s'est pas rencontrés quelque part *avant* ?

... Il semble que l'on se soient rencontrés, dans le passé à un moment où nos chemins ont pu se croiser.

*Avant* indique qu'il y a eu une date à laquelle la rencontre a été possible.